# Any tips for memorising acceleration in non-cartesian coordinates?

Tags: acceleration, calculus

I need some efficient way to pop up how acceleration in cylindrical/spherical coordinate looks like at the test.

Of course I could derive it on the spot, but it takes too much time (for me) and I thought it would be really cool if there's an intuitive hack for that. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question primarily about memorization techniques, even if the thing to be memorized is related to physics.

Comment: The question is about being able to remember some complicated equation, which can easily be done by getting intuition for the terms i.e. a good solid hand-waving explanation extremely common in textbooks, it's not about memorizing some passage on physics in some book like the Decameron or something...

Comment: Before the test, go through the derivation at least 10 times from scratch. Then you will have seen the final answer enough to remember it. There is no easy trick to memorizing other than practice and time and patience. Ask any basketball player for the trick to making 3 pointers: practice to build memory.